# An one program with multiple taskbar buttons

Tags: interface, mfc, taskbar

I have a problem creating my app. I want to create a MFC mutiple documents app. Not like traditional MFC multiple document app that all view windows are inside the mainframe and the app just has ONE taskbar button, I want to create an app that each document has a corresponding button in the task bar, that is, one app with multiple documents has MULTIPLE task buttons. ​A demostration of this kind of frame is AutoCAD.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How do I customize how my application windows are grouped in the Taskbar?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120820-00/?p=6813)

Comment: I did this some years ago, but don't know if it can be useful in any way to way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8514339/383779 My problem is: I needed to get multiple mainframes across the desktop space, don't remember if it created one button for each or one for all.

Answer (score 1):

A way to accomplish that is to choose "Multiple top-level documents" when you create your project:

[image]

Comment: This still can't produce the effect that every document in an app has it's own button in the taskbar, but at least gives me a clue to solve this problem. Maybe I can add buttons to taskbar manually and manage these buttons by myself. I think there are other things I must drill in.  And thanks a lot!